# Android "verify apps over usb" feature

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Android Jelly Bean has new developer feature called "verify apps over usb". Can anyone tell me what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Verify apps over usb** — Allows you to disable app checks for sideloading apps over USB, while still checking apps from other sources like the browser. This can speed up the development process while keeping the security feature enabled.

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html

It means during installation the code is verified against Googles servers if there is known malware in the app.

More in this blog at Computerworld, [Inside Android 4.2's powerful new security system](http://blogs.computerworld.com/android/21259/android-42-security)

Comment: Note that installing apps over USB is only available when "USB debugging" is also enabled and you use software on the PC, such as ADB, to load apps onto the device.  This setting does not affect installing apps by any other method.